# mysql database .ibd file size

Tags: mysql, performance, storage

MySQL `.ibd` file has grown to more than 3 TB and my RedHat box can no longer support adding more disk spaces.

## Questions

- How can I scale database storage ?
- What best practices can resolve this issue ?

Note:I use one `.ibd`file per table and have a couple of huge tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just storing data, your data mount for `/var/lib/mysql` should be 5TB SATA drives. If your application is write heavy, your data mount for `/var/lib/mysql` should be 5TB SAS drives RAID10.

If upgrading disks is out of the question, you need to do periodic table defragmentation in one of three(3) ways:

1. `ALTER TABLE myinnodbtable ENGINE=InnoDB;`
2. `OPTIMIZE TABLE myinnodbtable;`
3. Customize the defragmentation the table

You can perform this defragmentation manually as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE myinnodbtemptable LIKE myinnodbtable;
INSERT INTO myinnodbtemptable SELECT * FROM myinnodbtable;
ALTER TABLE myinnodbtable RENAME myinnodbtableold;
ALTER TABLE myinnodbtemptable RENAME myinnodbtable;
DROP TABLE myinnodbtableold;
```

Option 3 does not work if the InnoDB table has constraints because constraints will disappear.

Comment: Optimize table did it for me.